# Remote access informix on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, informix, remote-server

Im trying to create an environment with raspberry pi and informix db.

So when i connect with ssh, i can start up a server, connect in db and everything else, but when a try do connect from a remote client, in this case my laptop in the same network, the connection is refused.

I trying remote connect with DBeaver on linux mint to informixdb on raspbian.

Is my first experience with this configurations

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [compgroups](http://compgroups.net/comp.databases.informix/reconfiguring-remote-tcp-connections/2230731). It seems the default port 9088 is mapped for tcp6. Adding a new port in onconfig, sqlhosts and services, it can get the right protocol and starts work.[netstat -an | grep tcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCqb9.png)

Thanks